# HTTP response performance drops under load

Tags: php, mysql, http

I use following PHP code to measure execution time of PHP / MySQL scripts.

```
$start = microtime(true);

/* any PHP with HTML output */ 

echo (microtime(true) - $start);
```

This measurement always prints similar result regardless of server load. The execution time is most commonly 0.1 second across various pages completely unaffected by server load.

But when the server is under some load (100 concurrent users), each page takes several seconds to physically appear in the browser. From this observation I assume the HTTP server is suffering performance drops right?

Where should I begin to fix this issue?

Comment: Spread the load? Profile your code? Check your DB indicies / slow queries? Oh so many different answers.

Comment: @jonstirling I doubt it has anything to do with PHP or database, because the execution time keeps low at all times. It behaves as if transferring the HTTP data to the client took a while. Could it be low bandwidth issue?

Comment: Could it be? Sure, along with a long list of other things. Without actually looking at what is slowing down, you don't really know what's going on.

Comment: @jonstirling So what and how should I measure it? To check the HTTP performance. Any other measurements show no drops, except for website itself not showing on time in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put measures at the very start and finish of script to measure all php time.
2. Enable in your webserver (Apache or Nignx) time logging. For ex: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/tracking-application-response-time-nginx/
3. How many php processes are there? Check may be your requests are in queue waiting for free php worker? Try to tweak settings of you webserver of php-fpm (if you use it).

Comment: 1. Yes, php time is measured entirely beginning to end.
2. Will do
3. phpMyAdmin shows 12 processes during high traffic. I switched to nginx from Fast-CGI due to issues with php queue. Should I tweak anything in particular or in general?

Comment: 3. Depends on your system. Maximum number of simultaneously running processes is about 2*CPU cores. You may set more processes in fpm, but they will wait in cpu queue, consuming more memory. Check available memory and limits in config. If you try to use more than you have, you fall into the swap.

Comment: The hardware is not yet the bottleneck. In use is a Root server with 24 vCores (load at 15%), 120GB ram (91GB free), phpMyAdmin always shows swap usage at 0%. These numbers are from highest traffic time periods. Another observation and measurement is REST API written in php which communicates with iOS app. This API running on the same server also suffers no performance drop at all. The only visible performance change occurs when a webpage needs to load in a browser.

Comment: Try to measure all the stages of page processing.